# Destructuring Assignment for objects - is there a way to match the rest of an object? Similar to the splat when destructuring arrays

Tags: coffeescript

In Coffeescript, when destructuring arrays you can do the following:

```
[hello, foo, theRest...] = ['world', 'bar', 'attribute1', 'attribute2']

# hello = 'world'
# foo = 'bar'
# theRest = ['attribute1', 'attribute2']
```

I'm looking to do something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
{hello, foo, theRest...} = {
  hello: 'world'
  foo: 'bar'
  other: 'attribute1'
  another: 'attribute2'
}

# hello = 'world'
# foo = 'bar'
# theRest = { other: 'attribute1', another: 'attribute2' }
```

Sadly I can't see anything about this case in the docs. The idea is that I would like to grab everything that I don't know about, and possibly pass it on to another function that will handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's nothing like that in CoffeeScript. With arrays, it is easy to do things like:

```
[a, b, c...] = array
```

because JavaScript arrays natively support [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) extracting a portion of an array; there's nothing in native JavaScript like `slice` for objects so CoffeeScript would have to inline a loop to fake the non-existent `Object#slice` method. Complicated object restructuring with constants keys such as:

```
{o1: {i, o2: {j, k}}} = obj
```

for extracting `i`, `j`, and `k` from `obj` are easy because, well, the structure is known at "compile" time so the JavaScript is easy to generate. The justification for not supporting `...` with objects is, of course, just speculation.

If you want to do `theRest...` with objects then you could write your own function to do it, something like this:

```
deobj = (obj, keys...) ->
    ret = (obj[k] for k in keys)
    ret.push(rest = { })
    rest[k] = v for k, v of obj when k !in keys
    ret
[hello, foo, theRest] = deobj(obj, 'hello', 'foo')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r8hMa/

And if you didn't mind chewing up `obj` along the way, you could simplify it to something like this:

```
deobj = (obj, keys...) ->
    ret = [ ]
    for k in keys
        ret.push(obj[k])
        delete obj[k]
    ret.push(obj)
    ret
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rvC9g/

Comment: something like this could probably be used to implement the feature in the coffeescript project. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`lodash` has an `omit` function, `http://lodash.com/docs#omit`

```
Creates a shallow clone of object excluding the specified properties. Property names may be specified as individual arguments or as arrays of property names. If a callback is provided it will be executed for each property of object omitting the properties the callback returns truey for. The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments; (value, key, object).
```

`underscore` might have the same.

A coffee 'one liner' is:

```
therest={};for k,v of obj when k not in ['hello','foo']  then therest[k]=v
```

both require a list of key names to omit.  I can't think of a way of using the names used in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For destructuring assignments with splats, only the array notation can be used . The reason why object nesting cannot be used is simple - You need to know the property name beforehand when you use the object notation to destructure assignment . 
As you might have probably figured out , this will work.

```
{hello, foo} = {
  hello: 'world'
  foo: 'bar'
  other: 'attribute1'
}
```

But this wont.

```
{hello_new, foo_new } = {
  hello: 'world'
  foo: 'bar'
  other: 'attribute1'
}
```

The reason the second sample wont work is that the property names don't match. For your example the best way is to use the array style :

```
[hello, foo, theRest...] = ['world', 'bar', 'attribute1', 'attribute2']
```

this way, hello and foo are variable defined in the current function scope. and theRest is the array `['attribute1', 'attribute2']`

Or, you could use underscore to omit the kv pairs whose key names are hello and foo with [_.omit](http://underscorejs.org/#omit)
`others = _.omit(obj, hello, foo)`